# Sometimes after the redirection, the page does not get the correct state yet

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a website. When an anonymous visitor visits https://mywebsite.com/sign?next=/app, he can sign in by Google in a popup window, then https://mywebsite.com/sign?next=/app is automatically redirected to https://mywebsite.com/app, and the header shows his user name. Most of the time this workflow works. However, one out of 4 times, after the login and the redirection, the entire page of https://mywebsite.com/app is not informed that the user has signed in, for instance, the header shows `Sign In`.

So my question is how to make sure the state in the store is well updated before the redirection. Here are some pieces of code.

In `selectors/auth.ts`:

```
import { State } from '../store/reducer';
import { UserType } from '../services/auth';

export const getIsLoggedIn = (state: State): boolean => {
  return !!state.auth.user && state.auth.user.type !== UserType.ANONYM;
};

export const getIsLoggingInOrOut = (state: State): boolean => {
  return state.auth.IsLoggingInOrOut;
};
```

In `models/auth.ts`:

```
import * as authService from '../services/auth';
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux';
import queryString from 'query-string';
export interface User {
  email: string;
  exp: number;
  googleID: string;
  microsoftID: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  _id: string;
}

export interface State {
  user?: User;
  IsLoggingInOrOut: boolean;
  loginErrorMsg?: string;
  ssoLoginError? : string ; 
  registerErrorMsg?: string;
  next?: string;
}

export default {
  namespace: 'auth',
  state: {
    user: undefined,
    IsLoggingInOrOut: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    setIsLoggingInOrOut(state: State, { payload: { IsLoggingInOrOut } }: any) {
      return { ...state, IsLoggingInOrOut };
    },
    save(state: State, { payload: { user, loginErrorMsg, registerErrorMsg } }: any) {
      return { ...state, user, loginErrorMsg, registerErrorMsg };
    },
    update(state: State, { payload: { user, loginErrorMsg, registerErrorMsg , ssoLoginError } }: any) {
      return {
        ...state,
        user: user || state.user,
        loginErrorMsg: loginErrorMsg || state.loginErrorMsg,
        ssoLoginError : ssoLoginError || state.ssoLoginError,
        registerErrorMsg: registerErrorMsg || state.registerErrorMsg,
      };
    },
    redirect(state: State, { payload: { next } }: any) {
      return { ...state, next };
    },
    clearError(state: State, { }) {
      return { ...state, loginErrorMsg: undefined, registerErrorMsg: undefined  , ssoLoginError : undefined };
    },
  },
  effects: {
    *fetch({ }, { call, put, take, select, all }: any) {
      yield put({
        type: 'setIsLoggingInOrOut',
        payload: { IsLoggingInOrOut: false },
      });
      try {
        const routing = yield select(({ routing }: any) => routing);
        let user;
        if (routing === undefined) {
          const [u, _] = yield all([call(authService.fetch), take(LOCATION_CHANGE)]);
          user = u;
        } else {
          user = yield call(authService.fetch);
        }
        yield put({
          type: 'save',
          payload: { user },
        });
        yield put({ type: 'clearError' });
      } catch {
      } finally {
        yield put({
          type: 'setIsLoggingInOrOut',
          payload: { IsLoggingInOrOut: false },
        });
      }
    },
    *loginOauth({ payload }: { payload: authService.LoginOauthPayload }, { call, put }: any) {
      const user = yield call(authService.loginOauth, payload);
      yield put({
        type: 'save',
        payload: { user },
      });
      yield put({ type: 'clearError' });
    },
  },
  subscriptions: {
    setup({ dispatch, history }: any) {
      return history.listen(({ pathname, search }: any) => {
        const query = queryString.parse(search);
        let next: string | undefined | null;
        if (query) {
          if (query.next instanceof Array) {
            next = query.next[0];
          } else {
            next = query.next;
          }
        }
        if (pathname === '/sign') {
          if (next === "/reset")
            dispatch({ type: 'redirect', payload: { next: "/" } }); 
          else
            dispatch({ type: 'redirect', payload: { next } });
        } else if ((pathname === '/reset') || (pathname === "/")) {
        } else {
          dispatch({ type: 'redirect', payload: { next: undefined } });
        }
        dispatch({ type: 'fetch' });
      });
    },
  },
};
```

In `services/auth.ts`:

```
export async function fetch(): Promise<any> {
  const token = await getSignToken();
  let user;
  try {
    user = payloadFromToken(token);
    if (user.exp) {
      if (Date.now() > user.exp * 1000) {
        throw new Error('token has expired');
      }
    }
  } catch {
    user = await registerAnonym();
  }
  if (!user) {
    user = await logout();
  }
  return user;
}
```

In `selectors/header.ts`:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import { ICommandBarItemProps } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import { State } from '../store/reducer';
import { DEFAULT_PATH } from '../constants';
import { getIsLoggedIn, getNext, getUserName, getIsLoggingInOrOut } from './auth';

export interface IHeaderItem extends ICommandBarItemProps {
  actionCreator?: () => { type: string; payload?: any };
}

export const getNextPath = (state: State): string => {
  let path: string = DEFAULT_PATH;
  if (state.routing.location) {
    path = state.routing.location.pathname;
    if (path === '/sign') {
      path = getNext(state);
    }
  }
  return path;
};

export const getFarItems = (state: State): IHeaderItem[] => {
  const isLoggedIn: boolean = getIsLoggedIn(state);
  const isLoggingInOrOut: boolean = getIsLoggingInOrOut(state);
  const path = getNextPath(state);
  const logout = () => ({
    type: 'auth/logout',
  });
  const login = () => {
    return push(`/sign?next=${path}`);
  };
  const toMySubscription = () => {
    return push(`/my-subscription`);
  };
  const username = getUserName(state);
  return [
    {
      key: 'account',
      text: isLoggedIn ? username : 'Sign In',
      ariaLabel: isLoggedIn ? 'Sign Out' : 'Sign In',
      subMenuProps: isLoggedIn
        ? {
            items: [
              {
                key: 'signout',
                text: 'Sign Out',
                actionCreator: logout,
              },
            ],
          }
        : undefined,
      iconOnly: false,
      actionCreator: isLoggingInOrOut ? undefined : !isLoggedIn ? login : undefined,
    },
  ];  
  }
};
```

In `Main/Header/index.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'dva';
import { Spinner, SpinnerSize } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Spinner';
import { PersonaSize, PersonaCoin } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Persona';
import { Icon } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import CommonHeader from '../../Header';
import { ThemeContext } from '../../Theme';
import selectors from '../../../selectors';
import { State as IReduxState } from '../../../store/reducer';
import { IHeaderItem } from '../../../selectors/header';

export const convertActionCreatorToOnClick = (
  item: IHeaderItem,
  dispatch: any,
): IHeaderItem => ({
  ...item,
  onClick: item.actionCreator
    ? () => item.actionCreator && dispatch(item.actionCreator())
    : undefined,

  subMenuProps: item.subMenuProps
    ? {
        ...item.subMenuProps,
        items:
          item.subMenuProps.items !== undefined
            ? item.subMenuProps.items.map(subItem => ({
                ...subItem,
                onClick: subItem.actionCreator
                  ? () => dispatch(subItem.actionCreator())
                  : undefined,
              }))
            : [],
      }
    : undefined,
});

interface IProps {
  items: IHeaderItem[];
  farItems: IHeaderItem[];
  dispatch: Dispatch<any>;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  isLoggingInOrOut: boolean;
  profilePicUrl?: string;
}

interface IState {
  isSolutionSettingsVisible?: boolean;
}

class Header extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  private renderItem = (item: IHeaderItem): IHeaderItem => {
    const customRenderIcons = this.getCustomOnRenderIconButtons();
    const onClickReadyItem = convertActionCreatorToOnClick(item, this.props.dispatch);
    if (item.key in customRenderIcons) {
      return {
        ...onClickReadyItem,
        onRenderIcon: customRenderIcons[item.key],
      };
    } else {
      return onClickReadyItem;
    }
  };

  private getCustomOnRenderIconButtons = (): { [key: string]: () => JSX.Element } => {
    const { isLoggedIn, isLoggingInOrOut, profilePicUrl } = this.props;
    const loginElement = isLoggedIn ? (
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {theme => (
          <PersonaCoin
            imageUrl={profilePicUrl}
            size={PersonaSize.size28}
            initialsColor="white"
            styles={{
              initials: {
                color: (theme && theme.primary) || 'black',
              },
            }}
          />
        )}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    ) : (
      // <Icon iconName="Leave" title="SignIn" ariaLabel="SignIn" />
      <Icon title="SignIn" ariaLabel="SignIn" />
    );
    return {
      account: () => (
        // <div style={{ width: '28px', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
        <div>
          {isLoggingInOrOut ? <Spinner size={SpinnerSize.medium} /> : loginElement}
        </div>
      ),
    };
  };

  render() {
    const { items, farItems } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
      <div className="header">
        <CommonHeader
          items={items.map((item: IHeaderItem) => this.renderItem(item))}
          farItems={farItems.map((item: IHeaderItem) => this.renderItem(item))}
        />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default connect((state: IReduxState) => ({
  items: selectors.header.getItems(state),
  farItems: selectors.header.getFarItems(state),
  isLoggedIn: selectors.auth.getIsLoggedIn(state),
  isLoggingInOrOut: selectors.auth.getIsLoggingInOrOut(state),
}))(Header);
```

In `LoginPage/index.tsx`:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'dva';
import LoginForm from '../LoginForm';
import RegisterForm from '../RegisterForm';
import { State as AuthState } from '../../models/auth';
import { State } from '../../store/reducer';
import * as authServices from '../../services/auth';
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { getIsLoggedIn } from '../../selectors/auth';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import selectors from '../../selectors';
import { AppName } from '../../models/app';
interface LoginPageProps extends AuthState {
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  dispatch: Dispatch<{ type: string; payload?: any }>;
  app?: string;
}

class LoginPage extends React.Component<LoginPageProps> {
  loginOauth = (payload: authServices.LoginOauthPayload) => {
    this.props.dispatch({
      type: 'auth/loginOauth',
      payload,
    });
  };

  redirect = (path: string) => {
    this.props.dispatch(push(path));
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.props.IsLoggingInOrOut && this.props.isLoggedIn && this.props.next) {
      this.redirect(this.props.next || "");
      return <></>;
    } else {
      return <div>The sign in page</div>
    }
  }
}

export default connect((state: State) => ({
  ...state.auth, isLoggedIn: getIsLoggedIn(state), app: selectors.app.selectAppName(state)
}))(
  LoginPage,
);
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Do you have any theories about what may be going wrong?  That's quite a lot of code to review without some more details. Is there any way you can remove some of the code to make a more minimal example?

Comment: @Slbox I think we are missing a mechanism to make sure the store is updated and propagated before the page redirection.

Comment: In `/models/auth.ts` (~line 72) you're just straight-up ignoring any errors that occur during the call to `authService.fetch`, but by the time you've already dispatched your `redirect`. Is this just because we're seeing a heavily redacted version of your source?